# OpenMapTiles how to add more tiles?

Tags: openstreetmap, openmaptiles

I have built a openmaptiles server using official Docker container from Klokan Tech and I have loaded a map tiles from a specific region. How do I add more map tiles from other specific regions?

Comment: You might want to join multiple segments together ? ie. insert bigger .mbtiles file, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091006/best-way-to-merge-mbtiles-files-together/58210736#58210736