# Best way to merge mbTiles files together

Tags: openmaptiles

I have generated mbtiles for different sub regions of USA map from openMapTiles. Now, I wanted to merge all the generated mbTiles files together. What's the better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Once you have `tile-join` ( https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe )  tool, it should be easy. I am just patching version so it is easy to reuse same styles right away (for klokantech/tileserver-gl)

so my mixing script now :

`` rm mix.mbtiles
tile-join -o mix.mbtiles *.mbtiles
sqlite3 mix.mbtiles 'UPDATE "main"."metadata" SET value="3.8" where name ="version";` ``

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks Petrv.

Comment: Or if you need just snapshot of north america or USA , you can now get it from archive https://archive.org/details/osm-vector-mbtiles